# Ajax autocomplete not working with json

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? The server is returning JSON properly as far as I can tell. Example here: http://www.mediaworks.cc/test/sandbox2.aspx

The left textbox is the autocomplete. The right textbox populates when an item is clicked on in the autocomplete.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Sandbox2.aspx/GetPackages",
                        data: "{'term':'" + document.getElementById('txtPackage').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.HotelPackage,
                                    value: item.ID
                                };
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    document.getElementById('selectedValue').value = ui.item.HotelPackage;
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPackage" runat="server" CssClass="autosuggest"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="selectedValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `http://www.mediaworks.cc/test/Sandbox2.aspx/GetPackages` is not returning anything

Comment: I think you have that link wrong. Drop the /GetPackages like so: http://www.mediaworks.cc/test/Sandbox2.aspx. Thanks for looking!

Comment: No I mean, where are you getting the JSON?  link?

Comment: The only way I know how to look at the JSON that is coming from the server is by going to that link I gave, then use the browser's console to view the "Response". It shows that there is valid JSON there. I ran the results through a JSON validator.

Comment: The problem is your not getting response from the ajax.  check this http://s8.postimg.org/jnh7gv8jp/Screenshot_101513_124107_PM.jpg.  you're sending a wrong parameter (data)

Comment: This is what I'm seeing: http://www.mediaworks.cc/test/json.jpg I think you are looking at http://www.mediaworks.cc/test/sandbox2.aspx/GetPackages instead of http://www.mediaworks.cc/test/sandbox2.aspx

Comment: Any luck with a solution?

Comment: Better lets try to separate the work.  First get the json response from GetPackage.  Then load the autocomplete with json simply like http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/.

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` and `class` are referring the same element.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPackage" runat="server" CssClass="autosuggest">
```

assigning autocomplete to .autosuggest textbox

```
$(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
```

And the data part is also referring the same element

```
data: "{'term':'" + document.getElementById('txtPackage').value + "'}",
```

Both are same, which is wrong.

Make sure the **`data`** part is right

Comment: I appreciate you help. I got rid of the class and I'm now referring to it with the id like so: $("#txtPackage").autocomplete({ I'm not sure what else you mean. Could you post the code with your suggested changes? Thanks again.